# Why my query using WHERE does not work but my XPath query does?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have an example `xml` with this elements:

```
<tienda>
  <empleados>
    <empleado cod="B">
      <nombre>Juan</nombre>
      <localidad>Linares</localidad>
      <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="B">
      <nombre>Pepe</nombre>
      <localidad>Algeciras</localidad>
      <provincia>Cádiz</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="A">
      <nombre>Víctor</nombre>
      <localidad>Jaén</localidad>
      <provincia>Jaén</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="A">
      <nombre>Luisa</nombre>
      <localidad>Granada</localidad>
      <provincia>Granada</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="A">
      <nombre>Pedro</nombre>
      <localidad>El Viso del Alcor</localidad>
      <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="A">
      <nombre>Andrés</nombre>
      <localidad>Sevilla</localidad>
      <provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
    </empleado>
    <empleado cod="C">
      <nombre>María</nombre>
      <localidad>Guadix</localidad>
      <provincia>Granada</provincia>
    </empleado>
  </empleados>
</tienda>
```

There are some provinces (provincias) and I wish to retrieve only Granada and Sevilla, for example.

If I run this query with the locations in the XPath, it runs OK:

```
for $e in doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")/tienda/empleados/empleado[provincia = "Granada" or provincia="Sevilla"]
return $e
```

The result:

```
<provincia>Granada</provincia>
<provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
<provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
<provincia>Granada</provincia>
```

But really i want to use the clause `Where` and I tried this but the query retrieves all the provinces.

```
for $e in doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")/tienda/empleados
where $e/empleado/provincia = "Granada"
  or $e/empleado/provincia = "Sevilla"
return $e/empleado/provincia
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with the simple expression `doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")/tienda/empleados/empleado[provincia = ("Granada", "Sevilla")]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your XQuery to iterate over the `empleado` elements like this:

```
for $e in doc("LMSGI06.1.xml")/tienda/empleados/empleado
where $e/provincia = "Granada" or $e/provincia = "Sevilla"
return $e/provincia
```

**The output is:**

```
<provincia>Granada</provincia>
<provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
<provincia>Sevilla</provincia>
<provincia>Granada</provincia>
```

Your error was to iterate over the wrong elements. That's all.